# Culture specific dates Report Builder 3.0

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that will be published for consumption in both the US and the UK. I thought report builder would display the dates based on the users specific OS Culture. To test this out I changed my PCs Culture to French and the dialog in report builder showed the proper formats, but when I run the report it still shows in the US Format.

The backend SQL Database is in the US.

My other option is to use YYYY-MM-DD, but I'd rather show the dates in the users preferred format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the display format of dates, numbers etc. by setting the **Language** property of the affected textboxes (or the entire Report). If you don't set this property then these types of data are rendered using the culture settings of the Report Server (in your case this will be U.S. formats).

To make your report responsive to the culture setting of the client PC you can set the Language property (of the whole Report or individual text boxes) using the expression

```
=User!Language
```

More information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159642.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Just seems odd that it wouldn't use the users locale by default.

Comment: Ok.. so it worked perfect in Report Builder when designing the report on my desktop, but when I publish to Sharepoint, the english settings take over again. Any advice for me in getting it to work when published to sharepoint?

Comment: What version of Sharepoint are you using? I suspect that SharePoint is overriding the client browser language settings, so you might need to configure the language at the SP user profile or site level. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805087(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: We are on SP2010. I'll followup with our sharepoint support team. Thank you.